# FontAwesome url paths

Tags: gulp, font-awesome

I'm using font-awesome and the path that gets generated from gulp is the following:

```
/src/stylesheets/css/fonts/font-awesome/
```

and then the rest of url follows normally. This is indeed the path to the fonts but they do not appear. If I just manually change the path in the css to:

```
fonts/font-awesome/
```

then things are fine. I don't have any issue at all with bootstrap with the generated path as first noted. The css generated file gets placed under the "css" folder so then naturally going to "fonts/font-awesome" is not an issue but it's that full path it doesn't like.

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try absolute link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Hope it helps